# Show that $ d\left ( x_{n},y_{n} \right )=d\left ( x,y \right )$

Tags: real-analysis

> Question: 
>   Prove that if $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ and $y_{n}\rightarrow y$ then$ d\left ( x_{n},y_{n} \right )=d\left ( x,y \right )$

This should be a fairly easy question but for some reason I am not able to get the ball started.

Any useful hint is appreciated.

Comment: Use the triangle inequality in a proof along the lines of "if $x$ is close to $x_n$ and $x_n$ is close to $y_n$ and $y_n$ is close to $y$ then $x$ is close to $y$ ..." - bearing in mind that $d(x,y)$ is a constant.

Comment: What is $d$? What is $x_n$?

Comment: $x_{n}$ is an element in a sequence

Comment: Use what you know about $d(x,x_n)$ and $d(y,y_n)$ to bracket $d(x,y)$.

Comment: "Limit", rather than "=".

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d(x,y)\leq d(x,x_n)+d(x_n,y_n)+d(y_n,y)$ or equivalently: $$d(x,y)-d(x_n,y_n)\leq d(x,x_n)+d(y,y_n)$$

$d(x_n,y_n)\leq d(x_n,x)+d(x,y)+d(y,y_n)$ or equivalently: $$d(x_n,y_n)-d(x,y)\leq d(x,x_n)+d(y,y_n)$$

Proved is now that: $$|d(x,y)-d(x_n,y_n)|\leq d(x,x_n)+d(y,y_n)$$

If $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$ then $d(x,x_n\to0$ and $d(y,y_n)\to0$ so...

Comment: Thank you for the insights!

Comment: By the way, is the absolute bar necessary at the second last line?

Comment: Yes it is necessary. From $a_n\leq\epsilon_n$ where the $\epsilon_n$ are nonnegative and converge to zero ($\epsilon_n\to0$) it cannot be concluded yet that $a_n\to0$. For this you need $|a_n|\leq\epsilon_n$.